# Trouble with Shell $PATH and Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, bash, shell, path

I have mac ports installed on my computer. I installed ruby and rails using: http://railsinstaller.org/en

My .bash_profile

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

If I run

```
rvm -v
```

I get an error:

> "Warning! PATH is not properly set up,
>   '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin' is not at first place,..."

Now if I remove the top line of my bash profile `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:`
I then have no troubles, but mac ports stops working.

Someone who know Shell and environment would be of much help.

Comment: The first line of your bash profile removes anything put in the PATH variable before it. How about trying just one line at the top for the path: `PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: hey @luker thanks for the suggestion. When I change I get the same error.

Comment: 'Warning! PATH is not properly set up, '/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin' is not at first place,
         usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
         it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
         to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-2.1.0@global'.'

Comment: change your path to look like this, you can append it below the whole thing:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` this simply places `rvm`'s path in the first place, it must be either the last line in your `.bash_profile` or after what you have posted

Comment: @bijhaid still not working. Doing the same thing

Comment: What happens if you put the `rvm` bin path in the front of the PATH in your profile: `PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/bin:$PATH`. That seems to be what `rvm` wants. Although I would have thought that the `rvm` install process would do that for you, unless something changed afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use home brew. Don't use mac ports